# When do held-items take effect?

Tags: pokemon-tabletop-united

Specifically things like the Flame Orb and Toxic Orb. The only text I could find regarding how these items work says that it

> Induces [Burn/Poison] on holder. Off-Hand Item for Trainers. Standard Action to drop.

In the regular games, this only takes effect at the end of the holder's turn. Does this work the same in PTU? If so, how does this interact with time outside of combat, where 'turns' don't exist but 10-second intervals obviously still pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How Held Items work outside of combat is up to the GM

The section on Pokémon Items (page 296) states:

> [...] During battle, a Pokémon may be given a single “Held Item”. [...] On the following page is a chart listing various Held Items that grant a specific boon while held as a Static ability. [...]

So the question becomes how do static abilities work? The section on Abilities (page 310) states:

> [...] Most Abilities are passive effects, or Static in game terms, that are constantly on whether for good or ill. [...]

Therefore, things like Toxic Orb and Flame Orb are constantly active, even at the very start of battle. That said, I could not find anything detailing how Held Items or most other things work outside of combat. Whether something like a Toxic Orb or the Dry Skin Ability takes effect outside of battle is, as far as I could find, left up to the GM.

---

#### Flame Orbs and Toxic Orbs can be dropped, which *might* end Burn/Poison

Both of these items include the following line in their descriptions:

> [...] Standard Action to drop.

Whether dropping a Flame/Toxic Orb actually ends the Burn/Poison is something I couldn't find. I could see a GM ruling either way on this, but I would rule that Burn/Poison is the static effect of the item and thus once the item is removed, so too is the Burn/Poison.

Further complicating this is the fact that Burn and Poison are both Persistent Status Afflictions (page 246):

> [...] Persistent Afflictions are retained even if the Pokémon is recalled into its Poké Ball. [...] All Persistent Status conditions are cured if the target is Fainted. [...]

So if your GM has Held Items take effect outside of battle *and* has dropping Toxic/Flame Orbs not end the Status Afflictions, your only options left would be using Items/Abilities that specifically cure Burn/Poison or waiting until the Pokémon faints.

---

#### Regardless, Burn and Poison don't do much outside of combat

Burn and Poison only damage your Pokémon *if they try to take a Standard Action*. Thus, it is entirely possible for your Pokémon to be Burned or Poisoned (or both) outside of combat and not be suffering the negative effects because they are not taking Standard Actions.